# Writing Some Data from Multiple files using Python

Tags: python

I have 80 text files in a tabular format (columns and rows). There is an ID column for each file in which some may be identical. I want to simply write a new file, the file should have a header consisting of an id column and then 1 to 80 columns in which each column representing some data that will be taking from each file. Once each file is being read, it will take its id and place it in the new file id column and then will be taking 5columnsX4rows (20 cells) from each file and then place it in the column belonging to the file tag column. For the rest of columns of the files tag will have NA, something like the following:

1cvs id is only present in file 1. Cell of column 1 row x12 should have 
   5columnsX4rows.
  header

input file looks like this:
    file 1 for instance looks like:

```
id  readsfw  readsrv .......
1cvs  1        3
2jsh  4        6
```

output file looks like:

```
id     1     2    3   4   5   6   7   8 .....
1cvs          NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA ..
2jsh
shd
 .
 .
```

The way I have done the reading of multiple files is as follow:

```
def Read(pathname):
  with open(pathname,'r') as f:
     reader=csv.reader((f),delimiter='\t')
     for i,row in enumerate(reader):
       # How to work the code to do the writing as described above

try:
    folder_input = raw_input()
except Name_Error:
    pass
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(folder_input):
for file in files:
 if file.endswith(".tsv"):
  pathname=os.path.join(root,file)
  Read(pathname)
```

How can I do that using python?

Comment: Generally code should include an effort to accomplish your specification.  Can you provide the first draft of "# how to work the code to do the writing as described above"?  Also, example input and output files for the data you are working with would help.

Comment: Can you add some examples of the inout files?